# Wildfly option not avaliable for openshift v3

Tags: java, openshift, wildfly

I am creating a project using openshift v3 but was not able to find the wildfly 
option in my openshift web console anymore from today . Untill yesterday it is coming.

[image]

I am not able to find the same anymore

tried creating it through terminal like

```
oc new-app --name=netsetos08 wildfly~https://github.com/test/test.git
--> Found image 18929ed (2 weeks old) in image stream "openshift/wildfly" under tag "latest" for "wildfly"

    WildFly 10.1.0.Final 
    -------------------- 
    Platform for building and running JEE applications on WildFly 10.1.0.Final

    Tags: builder, wildfly, wildfly10

    * A source build using source code from https://github.com/sarthak0488/checkincode.git will be created
      * The resulting image will be pushed to image stream "netsetos08:latest"
      * Use 'start-build' to trigger a new build
    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "netsetos08"
    * Port 8080/tcp will be load balanced by service "netsetos08"
      * Other containers can access this service through the hostname "netsetos08"

--> Creating resources ...
    error: User "test@test.com" cannot create imagestreams.image.openshift.io in project "default"
    error: User "test@test.com" cannot create buildconfigs.build.openshift.io in project "default"
    error: User "test@test.com" cannot create deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io in project "default"
    error: User "test@test.com" cannot create services in project "default"
--> Failed
```

Not able to proceed by above also

Comment: What OpenShift instance are you using? Your own? OpenShift Online Pro? OpenShift Online Starter? If Starter, what instance? Or is it Minishift or CDK?

Comment: using OpenShift Online Starter and instance is starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com , It is avaliable till yesterday but from today it is not showing up.

Comment: Try logging in again. I know it isn't clear, but the error might indicate your login session expired. The tokens only last 24 hours. After logging in again, make sure you are in your project by running ``oc project``.

Comment: Missed that you said also removed from catalog in web console. Only paid attention to command line issue. Am finding out what has happened.

Comment: thanks .. now i am able to create through command as previously i have ignored to  create a project before running the new app command ..

Comment: but still wildfly is not available in my we console

Comment: I am unblocked for now i have created a application from terminal through oc commands

Comment: Yeah, ``oc new-app`` should still work, they just don't show in catalog. Is affecting a number of S2I builder images. Issue is being tracked internally and hopefully be fixed before too long.

Comment: Am told this should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue which is resolved.After some time options come back in the web console

but command line is working as usual fine

```
oc new-app
```

It is fixed now